# magento 1.9 "new" label not showing in catalog view

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, labels

I am not seeing the new label being applied on the catalog page. There are 2 labels  that I have applied but only one is working.

Here is code;
Sale Label

```
<?php if($this->helper('framework')->isSpecialProduct($_product)):?>
    <?php echo $this->__('sale_label') ?>
<?php endif;?>
New Label
<?php if($this->helper('framework')->isNewProduct($_product)):?>
    <?php echo $this->__('new_label') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Sale label works no problem.. But I can't get the new label to apply. Even when I filter the new products on the page so it is only showing them (so I know I 100% have new items in catalog) it still will not show the label..

Any thoughts?

Comment: do you want to show it on product view page ? please share code for `isNewProduct`.

Comment: Which criteria do you use for the new products, i.e. the products added within a certain days range (week, month etc.) or by the fields **`Set Product as New from Date`** and **`Set Product as New to Date`**?

Comment: @Pawan this code exists in the standard template for Magento on the template/catalog/list.phtml page and is as above(albiet modified echo text).  As mentioned the isSpecialProduct works no worries.

@MohitKumarArora I am using the `Set Product as New from Date` as the criteria for new on this instance.  Do you think this differs to a new item just added?  I have not tried a fresh stock add as all stock has been imported with no dates set for the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this with the following code

`<?php
        $current_date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
        $from_date = substr($_product->getNewsFromDate(), 0, 10);
        $to_date = substr($_product->getNewsToDate(), 0, 10); 
        $new = ($current_date >= $from_date && $current_date <= $to_date) || ($from_date == '' && $current_date <= $to_date && $to_date != '') || ($from_date != '' && $current_date >= $from_date && $to_date == '') ;
    ?>
    <?php if($new == 1) { ?>
            <span class="uk-label uk-label-success">New</span>
    <?php } ?>`

Does what I want and works as intended from the dates in product info